# GD image batch processing from directory

Tags: php, gd

Really racking my brain, I've been looking into this for 2+ days.

Goal? Click/select a subdirectory with images; on Submit, a batch process will run using GD on the whole DIR chosen, creating thumbs in a /thumbs folder on the same server.

Status? I can do this for a single file at a time, need to do multiple files at once.

Here's my functioning one-off code:

```
$filename = "images/r13.jpg";

list($width,$height) = getimagesize($filename);

$width_ratio = 166 / $width;
if ($height * $width_ratio <= 103)
{
    $adjusted_width = 166;
    $adjusted_height = $height * $width_ratio;
}
else
{
    $height_ratio = 103 / $height;
    $adjusted_width = $width * $height_ratio;
    $adjusted_height = 103;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(166,103);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,ceil((166 - $adjusted_width) / 2),ceil((103 - $adjusted_height) / 2),0,0,ceil($adjusted_width),ceil($adjusted_height),$width,$height);

imagejpeg($image_p,"images/thumbs/r13.jpg",70);
```

As you can see, the script is targetting a single file, I would like to iterate through a directory instead of specifying a name.

(I will also look into imagemagick, but at the moment it is not an option.)

I'll keep going through SO etc, but any help would be tremendous.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make a function from this code:

```
function processImage($filename){
    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $width_ratio = 166 / $width;
    if ($height * $width_ratio <= 103)
    {
        $adjusted_width = 166;
        $adjusted_height = $height * $width_ratio;
    }
    else
    {
        $height_ratio = 103 / $height;
        $adjusted_width = $width * $height_ratio;
        $adjusted_height = 103;
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(166,103);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,ceil((166 - $adjusted_width) / 2),ceil((103 - $adjusted_height) / 2),0,0,ceil($adjusted_width),ceil($adjusted_height),$width,$height);

    imagejpeg($image_p,"images/thumbs/".basename($filename),70);
    imagedestroy($image_p);
}
```

Please note last two lines of this function: it writes thumb basing on passed fiulename and destroys resource, to free memory.

Now apply this to all files in directory:

```
foreach(glob('images/*.jpg') AS $filename){
    processImage($filename);
}
```

and basically that's it.

Comment: dev-null-dweller, that worked perfectly. Thank you (and R.S) for replying so fast. I am new to answering on SO - how do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: on the left side of an answer there should be ✅, just click it and it will turn green

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I tried your solution and change some values to 150px square then when i run it, it works but when I checked the thumbnails, it has this black lines on top and bottom. the original sizes was larger than 150 which should be enough to crop the image to 150px.